# MaterialSwitch becomes completely purple when unchecked

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design

I was trying to use the Material3Switch but it behaves weirdly when i use the **Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch** style.

The switch becomes completely purble when it is unchecked even tho i don't have any purple color defined in my theme or elsewhere.[image: switch is unchecked]

[image]

My switch:

```
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:checked="true"
    app:showText="false"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch>
```

My theme:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/BLUEICE</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/BLUEICE</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/WHITE</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/BLACK</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceCornerMedium">@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.None</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceBodyMedium">@style/TextAppearance.Material3.BodyLarge</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Buttons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/WHITE</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/BLUEICE</item>
        <item name="elevation">20dp</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/BLUEICE</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">15dp</item>
        <item name="iconGravity">start</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/BLACK</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Materialcardview">
        <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/BLUEICE</item>
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/WHITEDARK</item>
        <item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="colorOutline">@color/BLUEICE</item>
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">10dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Bottomnav">
        <item name="itemRippleColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/BLACK</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Is it due to color being transparent? `@android:color/transparent`

Comment: That's magenta, actually, and it usually indicates missing theme attributes. This makes sense 'cause you're trying to use a `Material3` style with a `MaterialComponents` theme. That is, your app theme extends from `Theme.MaterialComponents…`. You should use a `Theme.Material3…` instead with that style.